# Git ignore does not properly ignore directories or files

Tags: git

I have a directory like:

```
/CALIPSO
+---.settings
+---calipso
|   +---.idea
|   |   \---dictionaries
|   +---dat
|   +---ico
|   +---log
|   +---objs
|   +---plot
|   +---plot_vfm
|   +---polygon
|   \---tools
+---dat
+---db
```

And my `.gitignore` file is placed in the root directory of the repository and reads:

```
\\calipso\\.idea\\*
\\calipso\\log\\*.log
```

So I'm trying to ignore the ideas folder and all `.log` files in my repository, yet I continue to commit all the files in these directories so I don't believe my `.gitignore` is working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well it wont ignore them once you staged them for commit.

Comment: @hitzg well, how can I **Start** ignoring them

Comment: `git rm ...` or  `git rm --cached ...` will remove them from the index (and also the filesystem int he first case). .gitignore should thenceforth apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If something's already in the index, it won't be `.gitignore`d.
You need to remove it from there:

`git rm [--cached][--] FILES...`

(`--cached` won't touch the working tree, otherwise the argument files will be also deleted from the working tree)

and commit the removal:

`git commit -m "stopped versioning FILES..."`

Answer (score 4):

When referencing folders for your gitignore you should not use backslashes. For example to ignore a the idea folder you should write:

```
calipso/.idea/
```

And for the logfiles since you want to ignore them in the whole repo:

```
*.log
```

Read more about it in the gitignore manpages: http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: what happens when the file reads it as `calipso/` , `.i`, `dea/` ? Or will gitignore not do that?